# python problem creating file and using file by its name only like 'sample.txt' not by giving it path (using v s code)

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCoTE.png)

every time i try using the file in python by using it name like 'sample.txt' terminal shows
no such file or directory
for solving it I had to provide the file path to it then only it works

solve the problem and provide me some steps by which I can surely avoid this problem next time
and read the terminal and provide the reason for it also it is showing

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

please help me with this too.

thanks

Comment: have you read the `print` doc, it explains the reason of the `AttributeError`

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Its necessary to open the file to print to it, and close it after. You will get the attribute error if you try to output to the file rather than the file object.
You can set the path and name of the file when you open it. See example below

```
demofile = open(r'c:\Temp\demofile.txt', 'w')
print(1,5,3,25,34, sep='->',end='!',file=demofile)
demofile.close()
```

Or using context manager to handle close

```
with open(r'c:\Temp\demofile.txt', 'w') as demofile:
    print(1, 5, 3, 25, 34, sep='->', end='!', file=demofile)
```

Comment: in Python 3.x we don't use `close()` anymore we use `with`